# Keyword struct before constructor name

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was amazed when I saw that this code success compiled with MS Visual C++.

```
struct foo {
    struct foo(int i): value(i) {}
    int value;
};
```

What means keyword `struct` in such strange context?

Comment: Doesn't compile for me with G++ 4.8. But MS vs2010 compiler accepts it. Smells like a weird parse bug. What compiler are you using?

Comment: [tag:Visual-C++], MS-compiler. Sorry, I must wrote this at discription.

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question is correct and it does indeed compile in VC++ (at least VC++2010) with no warnings. Not knowing the answer is not a reason to downvote. That this goes against the standard is neither.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour It was in the tag. Besides, that would deserve a question in a comment (which OP answered quickly, by the way), not a downvote or a close request.

Comment: I've re-upped the Q. This looks like a possible compiler bug (not a very interesting one, to be sure!). ACCU might have some insights, so I've just asked there.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I don't. We have a new user who asks a valid question and he immediately receives three downvotes and a close request just because he forgot a detail in the answer, which was nevertheless in a tag. This is not the way to welcome new members to our community. Just in case, I'm arguing against the behaviour, not the people who did that and much less against you.

Comment: This compiles in VS2012 and VS2013 preview too. I've raised a bug with Microsoft at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794504/keyword-struct-before-constructor-name

Comment: @cdmh So this probably goes without saying (since they are essentially the same thing, at-least for type declarations), but I checked, it allows you to do this with the `class` keyword, and interchange the `class` keyword and `struct` keyword as well. Very weird!

Comment: @MadScienceDreams yup, got that in the bug report. Thanks.

Comment: +1 @Gorpik Actually, the visual-C++ tag was added within the window where it does not show up as an edit, it was added after clarification was requested. Like I said I wouldn't down vote without giving the OP time but after reading many different threads on meta I know many others have stricter ideas on quality.

Comment: FYI, A response from Microsoft "After reviewing your reported issue, in the context of all the issues reported to us, we have decided not to take any action on this feedback at this time. We will re-consider our decision for a future release." (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794504/keyword-struct-before-constructor-name)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In most contexts, you can use the *elaborated type specifier* `struct foo`, or equivalently `class foo`, instead of just the class name `foo`. This can be useful to resolve ambiguities:

```
struct foo {};  // Declares a type
foo foo;        // Declares a variable with the same name

foo bar;        // Error: "foo" refers to the variable
struct foo bar; // OK: "foo" explicitly refers to the class type
```

However, you can't use this form when declaring a constructor, so your compiler is wrong to accept that code. The specification for a constructor declaration (in C++11 12.1/1) only allows the class name itself, not an elaborated type specifier.

In general, you shouldn't be surprised when Visual C++ compiles all kinds of wonky code. It's notorious for its non-standard extensions to the language.

Comment: There's one other addition: class defaults to private inheritance while struct defaults to public.

Comment: @IanM_Matrix1: That's the difference between using `class` and `struct` in a class definition; but we're not talking about class definitions here, just type specifiers used to refer to the class type. There's no difference between using `class` and `struct` there.